# Using a UIViewController as the default value for an optional parameter, but I get the "X does not have a member named Y" error

Tags: swift, default-value, optional-parameters

So I have been having fun with default parameter values.

```
class containerViewController: UIViewController {
    var detailView:UIViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        detailView = anotherViewController()
    }

    func hideDetailView(vc:UIViewController? = detailView){ // <- THIS LINE
        // code
    }
}
```

The line Ive marked produces an error:

```
'containerViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'detailView'
```

Ive been reading online, [including this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876985/class-type-does-not-have-a-member-named-variable-error-just-a-lack-of-class), but I cant seem to figure out how to fix this.

What I want is to be able to use `hideDetailView()` and if I send in a specific view controller as a parameter to that function, it hides that specific view controller. If I dont send any parameter, it just hides the current view controller that is held in the `detailView` parameter.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nil` for the default value, and check if `nil` in the body.

```
func hideDetailView(vc:UIViewController? = nil){ // <- THIS LINE
    let vc_ = vc ?? detailView
    // code
}
```

But In this case, you can't distinguish following calls:

```
// passing `nil` as Optional<UIViewController>
let vc:UIViewController? = nil
container.hideDetailView(vc: vc)

// use default value
container.hideDetailView()
```

If you don't like that, you can use `UIViewController??`:

```
func hideDetailView(vc:UIViewController?? = nil){
    let vc_ /*: UIViewController? */ = vc ?? detailView 
    // code
}
```